# Python - Error in authorized client request

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

Create an *"authorized_token"* Token object and use that to perform Twitter API calls on behalf of user

```
authorized_token = oauth2.Token(access_token['oauth_token'], access_token['oauth_token_secret'])
authorized_client = oauth2.Client(consumer, authorized_token)
```

Make Twitter API calls!

```
response, content = authorized_client.request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=computers+filter:images', 'GET')
if response.status != 200:
   print("An error occurred when searching!")
print(content.decode('utf-8'))
```

**Error** -

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute
>   'encode'

The error indicates the following code

```
response, content = authorized_client.request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=computers+filter:images', 'GET')
```

Someone can explain to me why?

Comment: Code and text formatting

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, can you explain, please?